# CoreNLP: Cannot find node in dependency for word said

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, dependency-parsing

Frequently when running CoreNLP I am seeing this in stderr:

```
Cannot find node in dependency for word said
```

This seems to happen for the verb that connects a quote to its speaker, which is pretty concerning for my application, quote extraction / characterization.

(**Edit**) What does this warning mean in practice?  Is this a known problem, and is there a fix?

Comment: which pipelines you are using and what is your sentence for which you are seeing this warning.

Comment: You're right, this problem happens when you try to process a text which has a verb indicating speech after a quote.
These warnings (which means no big worries) are meant to be fixed in recent versions of NLP, what version are you using? The latest?

Plus: *dkpro-core* handles this issue much better than Stanford lib, try giving it a chance.

Comment: @skadya, I'll be returning to this project in the next "duty cycle", about three days, thanks, will respond then

Comment: @dscastro yes, using the latest as of posting, 3.7.0.  Thanks for the tip about `dkpro-core`.  For this project, CoreNLP is a dependency that I won't change, but I'll check it out.

Comment: @skadya if it is a warning, does that mean there is nothing to worry about?  Or rather, do you know what this warning means?